# Node.js use variable inside js

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, babeljs

I have global variable:

```
version = "file-" + grunt.file.readJSON "version.json"
```

and want run grunt task:

```
babel:
  one:
    files:
      "dist/#{version}.js": "dist/#{version}.js"
  two:
    files:
      "dist/last.js": "dist/last.js"
```

But when I run grunt task, get this:
*Parse error on line 87: Unexpected '{'*

For "two" it's working, but for "one" no.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
  babel:   
    one:
     files:{
       "dist/#{version}.js": "dist/#{version}.js"
     }   
    two:{
     files:
       "dist/last.js": "dist/last.js"
     }
```

Comment: how is this different from what he did ..?

Comment: I use coffee syntax, so this brackets are not needed. But I tried what you advised, exact same error.

Comment: Can you tell me how version is generated. I believe you have to use `<%= %>` tags for `version`.

Comment: Inside version.json, I have this:
`{ "version": "0.14" }`
Problem not in version, when show this data in console, it’s shows correct data.